# WPF - Databinding Color to plain simple Window or Canvas in a Window Background - No controls

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I need an answer so i can explore. I am running into a brick wall here:

I would like to use:

```
        for (int c = 0; c < 255; c++)
        {

            Color = Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)c, (byte)(255 - c), (byte)c);
            Thread.Sleep(3);
        }
```

Each time the "Color" is recomputed, i would like the Window or the Canvas in the Window to IMMEDIATELY change color...so i get to SEE the cool color changes. Why is this so hard? I need to see this, but i'm hitting a brick wall. I copied a Type Converter here:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Color),typeof(SolidColorBrush))]
public class ColorBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color color = (Color)value;
        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

THANK YOU FOR ANY HELP!

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this in the UI thread. If you block the UI thread with `Thread.Sleep`, the UI blocks as well (and no changes are applied).

The solution is to use a Timer instead of a loop. Save `c` in some instance variable of your window. Set a timer that expires after 3 ms, increases `c`, changes `Color` and then resets the timer to go off again in 3 ms.

Alternatively, you could start a background thread that loops (and uses `Thread.Sleep`). In that case, you must apply the Color change through `Dispatcher.Invoke` instead of simply setting `Color = ...`.

---

To illustrate my point, here's a quick example of how to do it with a background thread:

```
// define the background thread
var colorChangeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
    for (int c = 0; c < 255; c++)
    {  
        // this (and only this) is done in the UI thread
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)c, (byte)(255 - c), (byte)c)); 
        }));

        Thread.Sleep(8);    // the background thread waits
    }
}));
colorChangeThread.Start();  // start the background thread
```

If you are using properties with INotifyPropertyChanged, you can skip the Dispatcher.Invoke and just set your property, see the explanation in Meleaks answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I'm looking for the basic plumbing. I can do the timer thing so the colors don't change so fast i can't see them. I'm having trouble getting the background to change color dynamically.

Comment: @woops: I don't really understand... where is the problem with the timer approach?

Comment: its not the timer approach at all. take the timer out of the picture completely. How do i databind a color generated in code to a window.background or canvas.background and the screen updates immediately to show the new color background?

Comment: In other words, i can just set up an infinite loops instead of thread sleep to see the color changes.

Comment: @woops: That's the whole point I was trying to make: The screen only updates if your code is *not* running, that's why you need techniques such as a timer or a background thread. It won't work with just a loop, with or without sleep.

Comment: @woops: Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful replys.. it works! I am not convinced "THREADING" is necessary. Here's Why:

Comment: How to i hit "return" at end of line without posting comment?

Comment: I tinkered with his results and got his version to run....no threading...just using AffectRender. Interesting but i am not able to convert it to just using a for loop and cycle through the colors.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of how you can bind a Color Property from code behind to a Canvas Background. Things to note

- Implement INotifyPropertyChanged. The Background for the Canvas will get updated upon OnPropertyChanged which will execute everytime MyColorProperty changes.
- Setting the DataContext = this; in the constructor will make all Controls in Window inherit this DataContext (unless this is overriden).

xaml

```
<Canvas ...>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding MyColorProperty}"/>
    </Canvas.Background>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    // ...

    private Color m_myColorProperty;
    public Color MyColorProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return m_myColorProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            m_myColorProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyColorProperty");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void SwitchBackground()
    {
        if (MyColorProperty == Colors.Red)
        {
            MyColorProperty = Colors.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            MyColorProperty = Colors.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
To run the Background animation you can use a BackgroundWorker like this

```
private BackgroundWorker m_changeColorBgWorker = null;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    m_changeColorBgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    m_changeColorBgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(m_changeColorBgWorker_DoWork);
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (m_changeColorBgWorker.IsBusy == false)
    {
        m_changeColorBgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
void m_changeColorBgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 254; c++)
        {
            MyColorProperty = Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)c, (byte)(255 - c), (byte)c);
            Thread.Sleep(10); 
        }
    }
}
```

You can set the MyColorProperty directly in the thread because changes fired by INotifyPropertyChanged are automatically marshalled back onto the dispatcher. This does not go for INotifyCollectionChanged however, just so you know.

Comment: while (true)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 254; c++)
                {
                    MyColorProperty = Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)c, (byte)(255 - c), (byte)c);
                }
            }

Comment: Thank you. Please see: http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/11/030337.html This works without threading, but uses the AffectRender Framework options in dependent property. I could never adapt this to my just wanting to run a for loop of color changes in a canvas background.

Comment: @woops: If you override OnRender and make an infinite loop there you'll hang the UI thread. What the example you posted does is that it draws a "gradient" background with 6 colors, not infinite colors as you're trying to do.